# RadWaitingBar not loading immediately on button click in Telerik Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm using RadWaitingBar in my windows application with a button which is used to load RadGridView on it's click function.

RadGridView contains more than 20000 records and it loads slower.

So I have used RadWaitingBar to display until the RadGridView gets loaded completely but the problem is RadWaitingBar gets displayed in the screen after datas are fetched from database.

Fetching datas from database takes some time in my windows application, I need RadWaitingBar to get displayed immediately once the button is clicked.

Please suggest me a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
Me.RadWaitingBar1.Visible = True
timer.Interval = 100
AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
Me.RadWaitingBar1.AssociatedControl = grdCNCFilesRad
Me.RadWaitingBar1.StartWaiting()
timer.Start()
```

Comment: Im reading [Meta-Post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) everytime you ask for Something. You are not making it easy! Please use some typo, some space and some BreakLine , because it'is really hard for me to read you.

Comment: I think that you are going in the wrong direction. Loading 20000  in a grid view should take no time. You can see an exemple of 50 000 result in the [demo application.](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/download.aspx)

Comment: @Pierre Lebon : Thanks for your update but anyhow i need RadWaitingBar  to be displayed immediately after button click